# Test server using real connections via Twisted + trial framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, integration-testing, twisted, trial

I'd like to create a series of tests between client(s) + server and I'd like to use Twisted's trial script so that I can display pass/fail status. Up until now, I've only used trial for unit tests and didn't need to use any real TCP connections. Currently, we have been thrown a curve ball and we must use a 3rd party server using a proprietary protocol which unfortunately doesn't have too much documentation and many of the outcomes are "unknown". So instead of simulating server data (and run the possibility of being wrong), I think it would best to simply connect our client app to the server and run test cases through trial. I vaguely remember a blog which had some examples using real TCP connections using deferreds, but can't find that bookmark now.

Any answers, guidelines, tutorials, or tips are most welcomed. My main questions are:

1. How can this be done without getting `reactor` errors? My initial attempt lead to a ton of errors (mostly unclean reactor) and failed tests which stop script cold in its tracks.
2. Does anyone know of some Twisted tests that are using real TCP connections? The docs do make a vague reference to some, but I can't find them or I have no clue what I'm looking for :)
3. Is there a better tool to handle network end to end cases?

Comment: http://mumak.net/stuff/twisted-disconnect.html this is the link that shows how to disconnect from a server.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you already answered yourself, [this article from Jonathan Lange](http://mumak.net/stuff/twisted-disconnect.html) explains how to disconnect.
2. [CalendarServer's tests](https://svn.calendarserver.org/repository/calendarserver/CalendarServer/trunk/txdav/caldav/datastore/test/test_sql.py) make heavy use of `Deferred`-returning tests for integration with the database (a postgres instance that [the tests spawn themselves](https://trac.calendarserver.org/browser/CalendarServer/trunk/txdav/common/datastore/test/util.py#L104)).  [Rackspace Auto Scale is also moving to Trial for integration testing](https://github.com/rackerlabs/otter/issues?q=milestone%3A%22QE%3A%3Aintegration%3A%3ATrial-based+scale-up+test.%22+).
3. No, of course not, Twisted is the best tool for all things at all times ;-).

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. I was hoping you or Jean would fly in for the save :). I've pretty much got it figured out now (after a whole day of trial and error...all puns intended). Hopefully I will either post an answer or I will make a blog post on what I've done very soon.